# Create Multiple Document Sets from List

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need a document set create for every name in this SharePoint 2010 list.  The Document set title is the first and last name of the person and the document set has committee name property that needs to be set as well.  The committee name comes from the same SharePoint list.

I don't understand wrong with my code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$url = "http://SERVER/etest"
$listName = "Advisory Committee"
$doclib = "TACM Application Docments"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url;
$list = $web.Lists[$listName];
$item = $list.Items;

$item | ForEach-Object {    
    $fullName = $_['Last Name'] + ", " + $_['First Name']
    $committeeName = $_['Committee Name']

    $cType = $list.ContentTypes["Document Set"]

    [Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{"Committee Name"=$committeeName}

        $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($doclib.RootFolder,

$fullName,$cType.Id, $docsetProperties)

}

$web.Dispose()
```

I get the following error:
ForEach-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Create" and the argument count: "4".
At C:\Users\ev\desktop\docset.ps1:10 char:23
+ $item | ForEach-Object <<<<  {
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

[DocumentSet.Create method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.create.aspx) expects the first parameter to be a folder ([SPFolder](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms464259) type):

> ```
> parentFolder
>
> Type: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder
> The folder in which to create the new DocumentSet object.
> ```

In your case you are passing an invalid object `$doclib.RootFolder` since `$doclib` is a `string` variable, probably you want something like this:

```
$doclibName = "TACM Application Docments"
$doclib = $web.Lists[$doclibName];
$newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($doclib.RootFolder,$fullName,$cType.Id, $docsetProperties)
```

**Example**

```
$url = "http://contoso.intranet.com"
$listTitle = "Documents"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url;
$list = $web.Lists[$listTitle]
$docSetContentType = $list.ContentTypes["Document Set"]
[Hashtable]$docSetProperties = @{}
$docSetName = "Archive"
$docSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($list.RootFolder,$docSetName,$docSetContentType.Id, $docSetProperties)
$web.Dispose()
```

### How to add Document Set content type into library

- Go to `Library Settings`, then click `Advanced Settings`
- set Allow management of content types? to `Yes`and click `Ok` button
- click `Add from existing site content types` link and select
  `Document Set` content type, then click `Ok` button

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I've updated the code.  However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: In that case please try to replace `$cType.Id`  with `$cType.Id.ToString()`

Comment: Btw, the example that has been provided in the answer is working for me

Comment: I received a different error with that. `code`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`code`

Comment: Make sure you are passing initialized values, my guess that `$cType` is null Are you sure content type for document set is retrieved properly at line: `$cType = $list.ContentTypes["Document Set"]` ? Maybe it should be like this : `$cType = $doclib.ContentTypes["Document Set"]`

Comment: i have Document Sets enabled on the site collection. I get this error when i change it to doclib: Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\eveale01\desktop\docset.ps1:12 char:31
+ $cType = $doclib.ContentTypes[ <<<< "Document Set"]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Document Set:String) [], Pare
   ntContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Otherwise this is the error message: ForEach-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Create" and the argument count: "
4".
At C:\Users\eveale01\desktop\docset.ps1:14 char:23
+ $item | ForEach-Object <<<<  {
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], MethodExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Comment: Enabling document set on the site collection level **is not enough**. Since you are getting document set content type from library, document set content type have to be added into it.  See the updated answer about adding document set content type.

Comment: Yes that is true. It is enabled and available as a content type. I guess it wasn't clear that I did that. I was just making sure that you knew that wasn't the issue.  My apologies for not being clear.

Comment: I guess it's not clear that I am fully aware how to enable document sets. I just didn't want you to suggest it because I've already did it.